# URL rewriting in .htaccess doesn't works as it should

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am currently coding my own website in PHP and MySQL on WampServer (local). I've already rewrited some of my URLs successfully. But I'm having problems with one of them.

I want to display on a page all my articles listed in a category using the GET method. For the moment, I  have the following URL : **http://localhost/actuco/cat.php?id=xpS3cc&slug=amerique-du-nord** and I would like to use and display this URL as **http://localhost/actuco/c-xpS3cc-amerique-du-nord/** (which does contains exactly the same GET parameters than the original URL).

I have tried to do this with the following line in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^c-([^/]*)-([^/]*)/$ cat.php?id=$1&slug=$2
```

When I write the second URL in my browser, it shows me a blank page with no code lines at all. My first URL works perfectly.

I'm really lost and I really don't know how to fix it.

Here is the whole .htaccess file used on my website (all other URL rewritings in this file do work).

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /actuco/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
#RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ article.php?lng=$1&yr=$2&mo=$3&dy=$4&slug=$5&total_slug=$6
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ waluty.php?cur=$1&amt=$2&lang=$3
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ url.php?mode=$1&u=$2
RewriteRule ^c-([^/]*)-([^/]*)/$ cat.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^bio$ o.php [L]
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

just pest this code in your .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

hopefully, it will work.

Comment: Should I add this to my file or replace totally the initial content with what you wrote ?

Comment: It doesn't works at all ! None of my previous URL rewritings are working ! Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Solved ! Just forgotten to add slash before $ in this line

Before :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ url.php?mode=$1&u=$2
```

After :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ url.php?mode=$1&u=$2
```

Now it works, but I still have a problem with multiple hyphens in slug described here : [Multiple hyphen handling in .htaccess (URL rewriting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53288730/multiple-hyphen-handling-in-htaccess-url-rewriting)