# Multiple hyphen handling in .htaccess (URL rewriting)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with URL rewriting. I have written the following rule in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^c-([^/]*)-([^/]*)/$ cat.php?id=$1&slug=$2
```

It gives me URLs like that : http://localhost/actuco/c-628Y8x-france/ (featuring the ID of the category, and its slug). This URL works perfectly.

But, when I type this URL : http://localhost/actuco/c-xpS3cc-amerique-du-nord/
it doesn't works anymore. The cause of the problem must be the fact that the latter slug contains several hyphens (amerique-du-nord) whereas the first one (france) contains no hyphens at all (I tried with all my categories with slugs including multiple hyphens).

Does anyone know how to solve this please ?

Here is my complete .htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /actuco/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
#RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ article.php?lng=$1&yr=$2&mo=$3&dy=$4&slug=$5&total_slug=$6
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ waluty.php?cur=$1&amt=$2&lang=$3
RewriteRule ^c-([^/]*)-([^/]*)/$ cat.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ url.php?mode=$1&u=$2
RewriteRule ^bio$ o.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
RewriteRule ^c\-([\w]+)\-([\w-]+)\/$ cat.php?id=$1&slug=$2
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks ! Could you explain please what the antislashes and "w" stand for ?

Comment: You're welcome! Sure, \w is a metacharacter in regexp, it stands for every standard letter and digit and the underscore character. The other antislashes were used for 'escaping' functional characters, like - or /.